# Integrating factor for guessing starting solution for SDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I need to know how to come up with a guess function where I can apply itos formula on and hence solve the SDE. Is there any systematic method?

For example:
$$dY(t)= 3Y(t)^{1/3}dt + 3Y(t)^{2/3}dB(t)$$
My teacher uses the guess function $$X(t)=Y(t)^{1/3}$$

Like, I don't know where this guess function comes at all. I have many of these kind of SDE:s and I want a method (systematic one) on how I can obtain these guess functions. I know the rest of the machinery.

Similiarly, why does the SDE

$$dX(t)=ax(t)dt+bx(t)db(t)$$
have the guess function $$Y(t)=ln(x(t))$$

I just don't get it where it comes from...
Big thanks in advance, been searching all over the internet.

Comment: It’d really help if you wrote down the SDE for others to see.

Comment: Of course :). This is one example (edited). I need to know a systematic way of how to start with a guess function where I can apply ito's formula. I don't get that part, and since if you use wrong guess function everything is getting messed up..

Comment: For the second SDE you write, the geometric Brownian motion, you might gain some insight as to where the guess $Y=\log X$ comes from by considering and solving the ODE *without noise* $dX_t=aX_t dt$ (classically written as $f’(t)=af(t)$).